# C# Reading numbers stored as strings from the same lines and putting them into arrays

Tags: c#

New to programming and I am facing the following problem:
I have to read the input below from user input and I want to put them into their respective array but I cant seem to figure out how do it.The numbers are separated by spaces. I would also like to use them as a integers later.

Input:

> 184 272 292 527
>
> 650 42 786 750
>
> 494 156 897 982
>
> 109 558 892 684

output

> arr a = {184, 650, 494, 109}
>
> arr b = {272, 42, 156, 558}
>
> arr c ... arr d ...

Comment: chunk your task into smaller tasks, then those tasks into smaller ones and so on, until you have the logic. Finally, open your IDE and code it. Giving you the solution won't help you to improve your skills. We **all** have been there

Comment: string input = "184 272 292 527";
            string[] a = input.Split(new char[] { ' ' });

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string input;
        char c = 'a';
        while(true)
        {
            input = Console.ReadLine();

            string[] arrayOfString = input.Split(new char[] { ' ' });

            int[] arrayOfNumber = new int[arrayOfString.Length];

            Console.Write("arr " + c + " = {");
            for (int i = 0; i< arrayOfString.Length; i++)
            {
                arrayOfNumber[i] = int.Parse(arrayOfString[i]);
                Console.Write(arrayOfString[i] + ", ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("}");
            c++; 
        }
        
    }
}
```